# Serverless DynamoDB not showing in AWS Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm learning the use of the Serverless framework to create and manage AWS services. I've stepped through deploying a Serverless project with the Docs on the Serverless site, but I'm not able to see the DynamoDB tables in the AWS Management Console for some reason.

I've checked that the AWS Profile I'm using is the correct one, and I'm able to post and get data from the table when I use the cURL from terminal, and am able to view data at those endpoints in a browser, but I'm not able to see any reference to the created table anywhere outside of serverless.yml file. Why is that? Please see the code below (full demo repo at this link: https://github.com/serverless/examples/tree/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb).

Would appreciate your help in learning the nuances here. Thanks!

---

```
org: justinbell714
app: jb-test-from-docs
service: serverless-rest-api-with-dynamodb

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <2.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  environment:
    DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"

functions:
  create:
    handler: todos/create.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: post
          cors: true

  list:
    handler: todos/list.list
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos
          method: get
          cors: true

  get:
    handler: todos/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true

  update:
    handler: todos/update.update
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: put
          cors: true

  delete:
    handler: todos/delete.delete
    events:
      - http:
          path: todos/{id}
          method: delete
          cors: true

resources:
  Resources:
    TodosDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

Comment: Make sure the region this is creating the tables in is the region you have selected in the AWS console.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much Mark. Didn't realize I had Ohio (U.S. East) toggled when I was profiled for Virginia (also U.S. East). 

If you want to break your comment off into a separate question, I'd be happy to upvote and select as the best answer.

Comment: It may not have been your fault. The AWS console has a propensity to switch the region on you. It seems, to me at least, that periodically us-east-1 users get thrown into us-east-2. There's even a handy Firefox plug-in that colorizes the console header based on the current region: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/aws-console-regions-color/

Comment: Haha. May just have to grab a similar plugin & thanks for the heads up on this @jarmod !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the region this is creating the tables in is the region you have selected in the AWS console.

Comment: Always this :-(

Comment: I may have missed it in the docs but it sure was a confusion. 
Thank you